# Convert ESRI JS Graphic geometry into WKT format

Tags: geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, esri-geodatabase, well-known-text

I am drawing an object on map and retrieving it's geometry using following code:

```
this.draw = new SketchViewModel({
    layer: this.drawLayer,
    view: this.view
});

this.draw.on("create", function(event: SketchViewModelCreateEvent) {
    if (event.state === "complete") {
        const geometry = event.graphic.geometry;
    }
});
```

Now i would like to store this geometry directly into esri sde database (postgres) using backend web application. This geometry is in esri json format. I can transform it into geojson format but still I cannot find any function that can save such geometry (esri json, geojson) directly into sde_geometry column. There are however methods to save geometry from WKT format.

So my question is: how can I convert graphic geometry into WKT format? Or maybe is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `arcgis-to-geojson-utils` library (see https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils) to convert ESRI JSON to GeoJSON, and then `terraformer/wkt` library (see https://github.com/terraformer-js/terraformer/blob/main/packages/wkt/README.md) to convert GeoJSON geometry to WKT format.

Conversion code could then look something like this:

```
var geoJSON = ArcgisToGeojsonUtils.arcgisToGeoJSON(esriFeature.toJSON());
var wkt = Terraformer.geojsonToWKT(geoJSON.geometry);
```

Comment: It's a pity there is no native support to such conversion in esri sdk. Your solution with Terraformer works. Thanks.